# Destroying unmanaged objects in C#

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I'm working on an application just now which uses a bunch of external DLLs to make a connection to a server somewhere.  Oddly, the exposed methods for these DLLs allow a connection but NOT a disconnection or close.  These libraries work fine unless you make a lot of subsequent calls to the server in one chunk, so what I decided to do was disconnect and reconnect after X amount of calls.

However, herein lies the issue.  I cannot disconnect because no disconnect method is given.  SO my question is, how can I totally kill this unmanaged object so I can recreate it again?

Comment: Sounds like your native library is broken, nothing C# can do about it.

Comment: Trash the junky libraries you've been provided and either find different ones (picking up the phone in the meanwhile to yell at whoever made them) or roll your own ones.

Comment: Sadly it's a massive framework for a fairly complex system, so rewriting isn't an option - and yes, the library is certainly not working at it's best!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find for this, was to run each call to the external DLL in it's own thread, which was eventually killed when the thread ended.  This was the only resolution that worked, given I had no access to updated DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using unmanaged resources in C# you should have your classes that use and interact with the unmanaged resources implementing [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and creating and destroying them with [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) blocks.

If you can't disconnect, depending on exactly what you're interfacing sometimes setting the variable containing your unmanaged resource to null will clear some of it up. Really though, there's not a great deal you can do without proper disconnect/dispose methods.

Comment: As I read the question, he can't write any meaningful code of `Dispose`, since the native library has a broken API. So I don't think this helps.

Comment: `using` does not necessarily means that at disposing, memory will be released. It will be released when Garbage Collector kicks in.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal `using` *does* mean disposing, in fact, `using` guarantees a call to `Dispose()`. However, as I think you're trying to say, indeed, it does not mean that disposing your class actually does anything useful. That depends on your implementation of `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually close the underlying connection to the server. I cant help you any more with how to do that without knowing more about the service your consuming (HTTP TCP ect?). You could put a trace (like wireshark) up and see what's being transferred.

Bottom line though is their software is broken. Can you not contact the vendor?

Comment: Sadly no.  They have moved away from the libraries to a web based service, and the business isn't in a position to move to that just yet (it's a massive undertaking to convert).